# An image picker returns uri `content://media/` without the extenstion in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, antd

I'm using an Image Picker from a framework called [ant-design-mobile](https://mobile.ant.design/components/image-picker/).

When an image is selected from the gallery, the picker returns an array like this

```
[
 {
   uri:'content://media/external/images/media/76',
   width:150,
   height:150
 }
]
```

How can I check the image extension (jpg/png) or image sizes at `https://mobile.ant.design/components/image-picker/`? Is there a library to do such things?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found on android to get a file extension is using 
`react-native-fetch-blob`.

You have to use the method `stat` from the filesystem.
Here's an example who should work with you code:

```
    import RNFetchBlob from 'react-native-fetch-blob'

    RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(PATH)
        .then(stats => {
            let re = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/,
                ext = re.exec(stats.filename)[1]
            console.log('EXTENSION : ', ext)
        })
```

Where `PATH` is your `'content://media/external/images/media/76'`

Hope this helps